# How to set a specifically year using Material DateTime Picker Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using the [Material Date Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) by wdullaer, and it works fine, i basically use :

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
MainActivity.this,
now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
```

But in my project I'm receiving the Date through the API and I need to specify that Date and not get form the Android Device!

Comment: So set an `OnDateSetListener` to get the date selected in the dialog.

Comment: Java != Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the date of the Calendar object you need something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
```

The then you can use the new calendar in place of your 'now'

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
```